# Flutter test goldens : possibility to emulate system bars to test SafeArea?

Tags: flutter, testing, e2e-testing, golden-test

I have a android/ios flutter app.

I handle SafeArea so my design/buttons does (or does not depending on the cases) conflits with system bars (navigation bar, status bar, notch)

But when i run my integration widgets tests (testing the full app with `flutter test` in headless mode, not in a real/emulated device) and I use the goldens matches (screenshot of the app), no SafeArea is used by the runner, so I can't test theses cases.

Question: is there a way to force/simulate fake SystemsArea to appear on each of my goldens to ensure my app behave normally with it ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Jscti, Didi you find a solution to this problem? I just boarded the same status bar problem boat.